# Using an IUsertype with an ID field in NHibernate 3.3+ Mapping-By-Code

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I am working with **NHibernate 3.3** and using the **mapping-by-code** system. The table/database I am working with is going to **read-only** for my application.

The problem I am facing is that my primary key column is stored as a binary field in SQL Server. I need to read this as a string, and unfortunately I cannot modify the table (including adding indexed views).

At this moment, I am trying to use an **IUsertype** to convert the value from binary to string.
However, I am stuck when trying to set the type of an Id column in an entity to use an IUserType.

I have managed to successfully do it for normal properties as the below example, but can't figure out how to do it for ID columns and foreign key columns.

```
public class ExampleEntity
{
    public virtual String MyIdColumn { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}


public class ExampleEntityMap : ClassMapping<ExampleEntity>
{

    public ExampleEntityMap()
    {
        Table("Table");

        Id(i => i.Id, map =>
        {
            map.Column("MyIdColumn");
            map.Type(???);
        });
        Property(i => i.Country, map =>
                                  {
                                      map.Column("Country");
                                      map.Type<CountryEnumUserType>();
                                  });
    }
}
```

1. Is this possible with NH3.3 Mapping By Code?
2. Must I implement an **IIdentifierType** instead to achieve what an IUserType does for an Id field?
3. Can a NHibernate transformer achieve what I am doing?
4. Is there another way to solve this? Other than retrieving the data and converting it in C#, as I have to do this for many columns in over a dozen tables.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I ended up using the ComposedId property to map the Id column, which allows you to specify a IUserType for the Id column.

```
public class ExampleEntityMap : ClassMapping<ExampleEntity>
{
    public ExampleEntityMap()
    {
        Table("Table");

        ComposedId(i => i.Property(p => p.MyIdColumn, map =>
                                                    {
                                                        map.Column("MyIdColumn");
                                                        map.Type<MyIdColumnUserType>();
                                                    }));

        Property(i => i.Country, map =>
                              {
                                  map.Column("Country");
                                  map.Type<CountryEnumUserType>();
                              });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution you mentioned works althought a bit of a hack.

For it to work the entity also needs to override Equality / GetHashCode, something on the lines of:

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Country == (obj as ExampleEntity)?.Country;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Country.GetHashCode();
    }
```

And when loading using `Get` needs to be done using:

```
session.Get(new ExampleEntity{ Country = Countries.Kenya });
```

I will try to figure out a better solution and post it here.